# Return different data in different mock API calls in jest

Tags: reactjs, api, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I am starting to learn more about testing React components using Jest and testing-library.
I've used mock API to return user data and render it in my test and want to return `user_active = true` in the firs API call and `user_active = false` in the second API call.

this is my code in **mocks** folder to mock getUsers API:

```
"use strict";
module.exports = {
  getUsers: () => {
    return Promise.resolve({
      data: {
        id: 27,
        full_name: "john doe",
        username: "jhon",
        is_active: true,
      },
    });
  },
}
```

this is my component and user info is an object that contain (id, full_name, username, is_active):

```
  class Users extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          userInfo: null,
        };
      }


  getUsers = () => {
    const token = this.props.token;
    myAPI.getUsers(token)
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
          data: res.data,
          error: null,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({
          error: error,
          data: [],
        });
      });
  };

  refreshList = () => {
     this.getUsers();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <a data-testid="refresh-button" onClick = {this.refreshList}>load user data </a>
       <span> {this.state.userInfo.username}</span>
       <span> {this.state.userInfo.is_active}</span>
      </div>
     )
    
  }


}
```

and this is my test:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
jest.mock("../MyApi");
import Users from "./index";


  test("load users twice", async () => {
  let baseDom = render(<Users/>);//first API call  
  expect(await baseDom.findByText("true")).toBeInTheDocument();
  fireEvent.click(await baseDom.findByTestId("refresh-button")); //to second api call
  expect(await baseDom.findByText("false")).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

How can I return different data in first/second API call?

Comment: Can you show your component and the test file of the component?

Comment: Yes. it is an complicated component. I edited the question and added some code right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `jest.mockResolvedValueOnce()` method, take a look at the [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockresolvedvalueoncevalue) to get more information of how the method works.

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import Users from "./index";
import myApi from '../MyApi'


it('should give two different results', () => {
  const firstMockReturn = {
    id: 27,
    full_name: "john doe",
    username: "john",
    is_active: true
  };
  const secondMockReturn = {
    id: 28,
    full_name: "jane doe",
    username: "jane",
    is_active: false
  };
  jest.spyOn(myApi, 'getUsers')
      .mockResolvedValueOnce(firstMockReturn) // will return to firstMockReturn object firstly
      .mockResolvedValueOnce(secondMockReturn); // will return to secondMockReturn object secondly

  let baseDom = render(<Users />)

 
  expect(await baseDom.findByText("true")).toBeInTheDocument();
  fireEvent.click(await baseDom.findByTestId("refresh-button")); //to second api call
  expect(await baseDom.findByText("false")).toBeInTheDocument();


})
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is a mock implementation, one simple solution would be to keep a count of the number of times the function `getUsers` was called and based on whether that value is even or odd pass `user_active` as true or false.

```
 export default {
  _count: 0,

  getUsers: function() {
    this._count++;
    return Promise.resolve({
      data: {
        id: 27,
        full_name: "john doe",
        username: "jhon",
        is_active: (this._count % 2 == 0) ? true : false 
      },
    });
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that we have a custom useAuth hook in our component to test, and in our tests, we are dependent upon the return value from this hook.

In our test.js:

```
import useAuth from "../thePath/useAuth"

jest.mock('../thePath/useAuth', () => {
  return jest.fn()
})
```

After that writing this line below before each render for each test, we can get back different values from our useAuth hook

```
useAuth.mockImplementationOnce(() => ({user: {role: 'admin'}}))
render(<Example />)
```